# Sunspot Solr - working with facets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I have setup faceted search using Sunspot, SOLR. Like this:

```
for row in @search.facet(:facet_id).rows
    link_to row.instance.name, :url_for(:search => params[:q], :facet_id => row.value)
```

My issue is that when I execute the faceted search in the controller like this:

```
    @search = Sunspot.search(MyModel) do
      keywords search_text 
      facet    :facet_id
      with(:facet_id, params[:facet_id]) if params[:facet_id].present?
    end
```

The facet counts are now calculated based on the with(:facet_id, params[:facet_id]) condition. I want the facet counts to ALWAYS be calculated without this condition.

Do I need to execute two searches? One for the search without the conditions (to calculate the facet counts) and one with the condition to retrieve the results. Or is there a way to do this in one SOLR query.

Thanks

Hamish

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solr has (and Sunspot supports) a concept called "multiselect facets", which is what you need here. Essentially you can tell Solr to ignore a condition (or multiple conditions) just for the purposes of calculating a certain facet. So what you'd want to do here is:

```
Sunspot.search(MyModel) do
  facet_restriction = with(:facet_id, params[:facet_id])
  facet(:facet_id, :exclude => facet_restriction)
end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there an easy way to have an 'all' facet? because @search.total does not exclude the facet from its calculation. thanks

Comment: There is an "all" facet capability, but Sunspot uses Solr Query Facets under the hood to calculate it, and (in my experimentation) query facets don't work properly with multiselect, even though the docs say they're supposed to. This may be fixed in Solr 3.1, though, so if you're targeting 3.1 give it a shot (it's the `:extra` option to Sunspot's `facet` method).